# How to annotate an annotation property in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I am attempting to place an annotation on an annotation property. My understanding is that I should be able to access it in code -- but I am not able to. What am I missing?

```
package com.example.annotations

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.reflect.full.findAnnotation

class AnnotationIssueTest {
    @Test
    fun testAnnotations() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(MyTestAnnotation::value.findAnnotation<PropertyMarker>())
    }

    @Test
    fun testRegularClass() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(MyTestClass::value.findAnnotation<PropertyMarker>())
    }
}


@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class PropertyMarker

annotation class MyTestAnnotation(
        @PropertyMarker val value: String
)

class MyTestClass(
        @PropertyMarker val value: String
)
```

When I run the given test, `testAnnotations` fails while `testRegularClass` passes. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason annotations of annotation properties don't make their way into the bytecode. However, you can annotate property getters instead:

```
class AnnotationIssueTest {
    @Test
    fun testAnnotations() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(MyTestAnnotation::value.getter.findAnnotation<PropertyMarker>())
    }

    @Test
    fun testRegularClass() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(MyTestClass::value.getter.findAnnotation<PropertyMarker>())
    }
}


@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER)
annotation class PropertyMarker

annotation class MyTestAnnotation(
        @get:PropertyMarker val value: String
)

class MyTestClass(
        @get:PropertyMarker val value: String
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly works but it's ugly. I found a related bug-ticket, but doesn't seem like it's gotten any action. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22463